# Vector find with pointers of custom class

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I am trying to understand operators you need to overload when working with custom classes in STL(SCL).

Can any one please tell me what is it I am doing wrong ?

```
class myClass
{
public:
    int data;
    myClass()
    {
        data =0;
        cout<<"Default const "<<endl;
    }

    myClass(int x)
    {
        data = x;
        cout<<"Int constructor"<<endl;
    }

    myClass(const myClass &m)
    {
        cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
    }

    bool operator == (const myClass &temp)
    {
        cout<<"Operator called &";
        return data == temp.data;
    }

    bool operator == (const myClass *temp)
    {
        cout<<"Operator called *";
        return data == temp->data;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    /*
    vector<int> myvector;
    myvector.push_back(10);
    myvector.push_back(20);
    myvector.push_back(30);

    cout << "myvector contains:";
    for_each (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), meObj);
    */

    vector<myClass*> myVec;
    myClass temp;
    myVec.push_back(&temp);
    myClass temp2(19);
    myVec.push_back(&temp2);
    myClass temp3(19);

    vector<myClass*>::iterator it = find(myVec.begin(),myVec.end(),&temp2); //works
    if(it!=myVec.end())
    {
        cout<<"Value is "<<(*it)->data;
    }

    vector<myClass*>::iterator dit = find(myVec.begin(),myVec.end(),&temp3); //fails
    if(dit!=myVec.end())
    {
        cout<<"Value is "<<(*dit)->data;
    } 

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong, but the first find works as it does a address comparison. What do I need to overload for the above to work ?

Do both the signature make sense ?

```
bool operator == (const myClass &temp); // seen in many places
bool operator == (const myClass *temp); // what if two pointer types of same object are being compared?
```

Cheers!

Comment: Do you really need a vector<T*> in your case? If yes, please do check out Boost's pointer container (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: Well , this is just an understanding experiment. As i always thought while dealing with dynamic memory allocations you would be "saving" the address of the element rather than the element twice in your program.i.e. once on new & one copy in the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator overloads must have at least one user-defined type.  So you cannot overload `operator==` for two pointers, for instance.

Your `myClass::operator==(const myClass *temp)` is valid in the sense that it compiles, but makes very little semantic sense, and is not recommended (there are very few situations where you'd want to do `T x; T *y; ... (x == y)`).

For your situation, where you have a vector of pointers, you may want to consider `std::find_if`, which takes a *predicate*.  Something like:

```
class CompareByPointer
{
public:
    explicit CompareByPointer(const myClass &p) : p(p) {}
    bool operator() (const myClass &rhs) const { return p->data == rhs->data; }
private:
    const myClass &p;
};

...

find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), CompareByPointer(&temp2));
```

*[As a side note, you should generally define member functions `const` wherever possible.  So your operator overloads should be `const`.]*

Comment: Perhaps i am missing something, does that mean you cannot use operations like find on a container which contains pointers of user defined types?

Comment: @Ricko: You can, but it will be comparing the pointers themselves, not what is being pointed to.

Comment: @Ricko: yes and no. As said, overloaded operators can only be applied to user defined types. But instead of `find`, you can use `find_if`, for example, which, instead of using overloaded operators, uses a user-specified predicate function

Comment: Thanks guys! Just another thing to clarify, when you say at least one user defined type , are you referring to the other case as implicit conversion of built in types to user defined types via non explicit constructor ?

Comment: @Ricko: The compiler will attempt to resolve the operator overload with up to one implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

In the sample code, you haven't pushed `&temp3` into `myVec`. So it makes sense for the second `std::find` to fail.

Comment: yep, that was on purpose though. I wanted to see if there were any operators i could overload to get the "correct" logical result.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "work" in this case?  Generally, when you're storing pointers, it's because the objects do have identity, and comparing the address is the correct thing to do.  Otherwise, you should probably be storing values (although there are exceptions).  Anyway, you can always use `find_if`, and any comparison criteria you want.  For anything but the simplest types, I find myself using `find_if` more often than `find` anyway; usually, you're not looking for equality, but rather for some specific type of match. Here, for example, you'd more likely want something like:

```
std::vector<MyClass>::iterator it = std::find_if( myVect.begin(), myVect.end(),
                                                  boost::bind(&MyClass::id, _1, 19) );
```

(Supposing that the `data` here is some sort of identifier, and that you've provided a member function, `myClass::id()` to read it.)

Comment: By work i mean , a comparison should ideally return true. This is something akin to bit-by-bit comparison as opposed to actual comparison of values.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand.  Under what conditions should the comparison return true?  As I said, you've decided to deal with pointers.  The most likely reason is that each object has an identity, and the objects are only "equal" if they are the same object.  Otherwise, use values, not pointers.  (Which is one of my points---the other is that you probably want `find_if` anyway, since you don't want to have to create a complete object just to test if the object's identifier is 19.)